# WordPress JSON API with Android AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-asynctask

I'm trying to create an application that retrieves data from Wordpress. I'm using the Wordpress JSON API for that. In my app, I have a `JSONAsyncTask` class that retrieves data using an HTTPClient, Post, and Response. When the JSON data (or any type of data the URL returns) is retrieved, it creates a Toast that prints it out. It works with every URL except for: http://www.mcpestuffs.com/wp-json

I have no idea what's going on here...

Here is my AsyncTask class:

```
public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    String responseData;

    public JSONAsyncTask(){

        responseData = "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        print("Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int stat = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(stat == 200){

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                responseData = data;

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        processData();
    }

    private void processData(){

        print(responseData);

    }

}
```

Comment: When it doesn't work, does it print out any error? If it does, please update your question with the error trace.

Comment: @iRuth It doesn't seem to be pritin

Comment: @iRuth It doesn't seem to be printing out an error

Comment: @arjay07 Please post 1 URL that this code works for.

Comment: @iRuth Almost every URL that links to a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you remove the if-statement `if (stat == 200){` because you are only processing your response when the response code is 200.

You should process your response even when the response code is not 200.

It is possible that you are getting a response from the server under a different response code. Check [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for more on HTTP response codes

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
responseData = data;
```

I hope this helps.